# How to flip axis order in WKT/CRS with GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools

I'm trying to generate some WKT for a CRS where we've flipped the axis order to make it play nicely with shapefiles.   For example, we've got some points in `EPSG:2193` (NZ transverse mercator, in `yx` order), but when we write it out we have to flip it to `xy` so that software (like qgis), which ignores the axis order in the `.prj` and respects the shapefile convention, can read it properly.

We're doing this in some java software that uses JTS and GeoTools and realistically it has to be implemented in the java process space (no shelling out to GDAL or something like that :) ).

Our simple approach for building the new CRS (for a math transform - but we might swap this for a simple coordinatefilter which does the x-y swap) and WKT (for the `.prj` file) is to do something like:

```
// generate epsg code from arbitrary CRS
String srsCode = CRS.toSRS(crs);
// construct a CRS from the epsg code with force longitude first
crs = CRS.decode(srsCode, true);
// Get wkt for the new flipped CRS
String wkt = newCrs.toWKT();
```

This seems to work and will write out a `.prj` with the `EAST, NORTH` order

I was wondering if there's a way to programmatically set the projection's axis in a CRS so that we can not worry about srs codes.  The java object model for CRS looks pretty  immutable and doesn't seem to have some sort of clone/edit API , so might be hard to go that route, so was thinking one route might be to edit the WKT, either by removing the AXIS order or editing it.  Ideally, this would be on a parse tree, rather than on the text - maybe the XML representation might be a little cleaner/simpler to edit?

Or maybe this is just unnecessary and maybe "I'm doing it wrong"?

Thoughts?

Comment: have you looked at the solutions in the [FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide/library/referencing/order.html)? Also I don't think QGIS ignores the .prj or your points would be in the wrong place completely. The problem seems to be that unlike (https://epsg.io/27200) which 2193 replaces it doesn't specify an axis order

Comment: Axis order of EPSG:2193 is specified to be Northing-Easting in the current EPSG database https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/2193. Was it missing in some older database version?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer - it doesn't ignore the `.prj`, it ignores the axis order that's in the `.prj`